# Are multiple source files being passed to gcc treated as a single translation unit?

Tags: c, gcc, lto, translation-unit

I think I've read that compiling multiple files with `gcc` at the same time would achieve the same thing as adding all sources into a single source file, as per [Single Compilation Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Compilation_Unit), but I can't find any sources on that anymore. Is that true?

We are currently trying to shrink a binary to the smallest size possible and are applying multiple techniques to achieve that. We reached the point where the discussion is about the differences between Single Compilation Unit, [Link Time Optimization](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/LinkTimeOptimization) and changing the build to compile all sources in a single compiler call, something like `gcc -o binary $CFLAGS $INCLUDES $CDEFS a.c b.c c.c d.c e.c`.

Comment: To the question in the title: No.

Comment: Dirty hack: create a separate source file that `#include`'s the other source files and compile that.

Comment: @dbush Not going to work if these have for example, `static` variables with same name.

Comment: @dbush oh-oh. Better amalgamate it through the script. `include` on .c file is just an abomination. And Eugene is correct too.

Comment: many linkers now support linked time optimization (lto).

Comment: @SergeyA You are familiar with the term "Dirty hack"? ;)

Comment: Have you tried compiling with the `-s` option to strip the symbols from the executable? It should reduce the binary's size and make it super fun to debug any run time issues.

Comment: LTO is probably the closest you will get to a compiler being able to optimize multiple translation units as if the code were refactored to coexist in a single translation unit.

Comment: @Sergey that is called a unity build and is not an abonimation, it’s something great.

Comment: @Fredrik "One man's meat is another man's poison". Suit yourself.

Comment: As far as I know, the C standard does not say anything about this so it's upp to the compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Each independent .c file passed to a compiler is considered a single translation unit, so multiple files passed to a compiler produce multiple independent translation units.

Comment: For OP's reference, you can easily verify this by just running the suggested command under `strace -f`. You'll see the compiler invoked for each source file, and then the assembler invoked for the same number of temporary .s files, followed by the linker.

Comment: Or just run it with `-c` and observe the bunch of object files generated.

Comment: Using `gcc -v` (verbose) also shows what commands are executed, and therefore each source file being processed separately.

Comment: What are independent .c files? If code in one of the .c files depends on code in another, are they treated as one translation unit?

Comment: @EricPostpischil independent here means 'separate' or 'individual'. Each .c file is a single translation unit, period.

Comment: @SergeyA: Do you think students will all know that? Or should it be in your answer? Also, if `a.c` includes separate file `b.c`, are they different units because they are separate and individual files or one unit because one depends on the other? How should a student know how to answer this?